# Unipotent matrices in image of exponential function

Tags: linear-algebra

I have already proved that the exponential function is continuous on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, now, how do I prove that the set of unimodular matrices,  $\mathrm{Uni}_n(\mathbb{C})$, is a subset of $\exp(M_n(\mathbb{C}))$?

I have tried to do something with Jordan blocks - is it true that any unimodular matrix is similar to a matrix composed of Jordan blocks with all eigenvalues equal to $1$?

Comment: You can define a natural logarithm function on $\operatorname{Uni}_n\left(\mathbb{C}\right)$ simply by plugging the matrix into the Mercator series for the logarithm. This works because if you subtract $1$ from a unipotent matrix, you get a nilpotent matrix.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Which means that all Jordan blocks are in the image as well, establishing a surjection $\exp:M_n(\mathbb{C})\to \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ because the logarithm and exponential both act blockwise?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, assuming that you can show that the image of $\exp$ is closed under conjugation.